# javascript (no jquery) - load a local json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a local JSON file which I converted into a JS object by adding `var data = ...` in front of that:

```
var data = {
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Martin",
            "surname": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "surname": "Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I load it with: `<script src="data.json" type="text/javascript">` and try to parse it with:

```
var h = JSON.parse(data);
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: You don't have to parse it. The JavaScript parser will do that for you implicitly, and your variable `data` is ready to use.

Comment: What's your question? You can't use `JSON.parse` because it's not JSON anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put `var data = {` in front of it, it stops being JSON and becomes JavaScript. (So you shouldn't give it a `.json` file extension and that will encourage servers to tell browsers that it is JSON and not JS).

In this case, it is a JavaScript program that assigns an **object** to a variable.

`JSON.parse` takes a **string** containing JSON and converts it into a JavaScript object (or array or other data type).

Don't parse it. It is already parsed by the JavaScript compiler.

Comment: Ok I understand. Is there a way of loading a JSON file then? I have read for security reasons, it's not possible to load a local file. So how do people work with json files and javascript? I'm learning js, I don't really want to get into jquery. Thank you.

Comment: Use a webserver and load the data over HTTP with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. For now, I'm going to be use what was advised above (no JSON.parse). Having said that, I'll also google for XMLHttpRequest to learn it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here [MZN JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can see what `JSON.parse()` should be used for. It is used on a `String` that contains a JSON object, and this method would parse it into the format that your `data` variable is already in. Since your `data` variable is already in JSON format, your variable is ready to use and you do not need the `JSON.parse()` method.